# Removing Super Cache Plugin

Tags: plugins

I want to remove super cache off my site

I do every thing in this article
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/other_notes/

The only problem I am having is the htaccess file.  If I remove the stuff that super cache
put in the htaccess file I get a 500 Internal error on my site

If I put back the code that the plguin put in it fixes it... I have always noticed this on my wordpress blogs when i  play with the hataccess file with sites that have super cache, how can I clean my htacess file up?

Answer (score 1):

Don't attempt to clean it, deactivate supercache, then manually remove the entire `.htaccess` file, delete it. Finally, go to your permalinks page, and re-save your settings. One of two things will happen:

- WordPress will regenerate your htaccess
- WordPress will hand you some new rules

Comment: not working, i even set my permissions to 777 on the file, they wont leave

Comment: What won't leave? I don't understand

Comment: Do you mean A: the 500 errors return B: the .htaccess won't remove itself C: The Supercache htacess rules are back ( this should all be done after supercache is deactivated )

Comment: I was saying that I uninstalled the plugin.. all the supercache rules were still remainiing in htaccess.  When I try to remove them I got a 500 error.  If I tried to resave from permalinks hoping to refresh the htaccess, the rules would still stay:)   I managed to get rid of it by reinstannling the plugin, setting my wp content to 777 temporary then doing the permalink, just a bit annoyiing to get off